# What is the sum $\sum_{m} e^{i (U_m k + \beta_m)} $ when $U$ and $\beta$ follow different distributions

Tags: probability, summation, expected-value, random-functions

I have the following function.

$$ x(k) = \sum_{m} e^{i (U_m k + \beta_m)} $$

$i = \sqrt{-1}$

Here, $U_m$ are samples drawn from a Gaussian random distribution.

$$ U_m \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma) $$ and $\beta_i$ are samples drawn from an uniform distribution.

$$ \beta_m \sim \mathcal{U}[-\pi, +\pi] $$.

I want to write $x$ as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ like this,

$$ x(k) = f(k, \mu, \sigma) $$ when the number of samples summed in $x$ tends to $\infty$.

The solution I tried so far:

I used the expected value principles,

First I took the first term in the sum that is

$$ \sum_{m} e^{i U_m k} = ( \mathbb{E}[e^{i U}] ) \times ( \mathbb{E[U]} ) N = N \mu e^{-\sigma^2 k^2 /2}  e^{i \mu k} $$ where $N$ is the number of samples.

The same I did for the second term and it turns out to be $0$.

$$ \sum_{m} e^{i \beta_i} = ( \mathbb{E}[e^{i \beta}] ) \times ( \mathbb{E[\beta]} ) N = 0$$

The first term suggests that the signal is decaying with $k \sigma$ and the second one suggests that the sum should be $0$. When I remove the second term from the original numerical sum and plot the function with $k$, I see in the simulation that the signal is indeed decaying.

However, when I add the second term, it becomes like a periodic signal. So, it doesn't hold the properties of both analysis I did. I guess I am missing something. The numerical sum I am getting is the expected one I believe as it is periodic and finite as $k$ increases.

============ THE SIMULATION ===============================

```
clear;
close all;


Mu = 7.5 .* 0.4189;
Sigma = 1 .*  0.4189;

Nt = 128;

K = 0:1:Nt-1;


x = zeros(1, Nt);

Nu = 100000;
beta = -pi + 2 * pi .* rand([1 Nu]);
    
U = normrnd(Mu, Sigma, [1 Nu]);

for k = 1:Nt

    x(k) = [sum(exp(1j .* K(k) .* U + 1j .* beta) )];

end



figure; plot(real(x)); hold on; plot(imag(x)); grid on;
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

With respect to $k$, this sum is still a periodic signal. I can agree with this because after all, it is a sum of periodic signals. I have used the number of points in the sum to be $100000$. The number of $k$ points is $128$. How can I correctly write the original sum as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ ?

========================== EDIT =========================================

I did some more analysis and found the distribution of $e^{i (U_m k + \beta)}$. I don't know how to approach the sum after this to get a statistical analysis of $x$ when some finite number of samples are taken in $k$ domain.

Understanding the function inside the sum:

I deduced the distribution of $U_m k + \beta_m$. It looks like the following. It is a convolution of both distributions.

$$ p(x) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{2 \pi k^2 \sigma^2}} e^{-(kx - k\mu - \tau)/(2k^2\sigma^2)} d\tau $$

$$ p(x) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \Big[ \operatorname{erf}\Big(\frac{k\mu-x+2\pi}{\sqrt{2}k\sigma}\Big) - \operatorname{erf}\Big(\frac{k\mu-x}{\sqrt{2}k\sigma}\Big) \Big] $$

I used the CDF technique to find the distribution of $\cos((U_m k + \beta_m))$.

$$ F(y) = p(Y \leq y) = p(\cos(X) \leq y) = p(X \leq \cos^{-1}(y))$$

$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\cos^{-1}(y)} \frac{1}{4\pi} \Big[ \operatorname{erf}\Big(\frac{k\mu-x+2\pi}{\sqrt{2}k\sigma}\Big) - \operatorname{erf}\Big(\frac{k\mu-x}{\sqrt{2}k\sigma}\Big) \Big] dx $

I have seen that the function inside the integral is $0$ at $-\infty$ so the expression becomes,

$$ F(y) = \frac{\left(k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)}{\sqrt{2} k \sigma}\right)+\left(-k \mu+\cos ^{-1}(y)-2 \pi \right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)+2 \pi }{\sqrt{2} k \sigma}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} k \sigma \left(e^{-\frac{\left(\cos ^{-1}(y)-k \mu\right)^2}{2 k^2 \sigma^2}}-e^{-\frac{\left(k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)+2 \pi \right)^2}{2 k^2 \sigma^2}}\right)}{4 \pi } $$

Then I took the derivative in terms of $y$ of this expression to find the pdf of $\cos(x)$, that is the pdf of $\cos(U_m k + \beta_m)$

$$ g(y) = \frac{\frac{\text{erf}\left(\frac{k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)}{\sqrt{2} k \sigma}\right)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}-\frac{\text{erf}\left(\frac{k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)+2 \pi }{\sqrt{2} k \sigma}\right)}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} k \sigma \left(\frac{\left(k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)+2 \pi \right) e^{-\frac{\left(k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)+2 \pi \right)^2}{2 k^2 \sigma^2}}}{k^2 \sigma^2 \sqrt{1-y^2}}+\frac{\left(\cos ^{-1}(y)-k \mu\right) e^{-\frac{\left(\cos ^{-1}(y)-k \mu\right)^2}{2 k^2 \sigma^2}}}{k^2 \sigma^2 \sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(k \sigma-\cos ^{-1}(y)\right) e^{-\frac{\left(k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)\right)^2}{2 k^2 \sigma^2}}}{k \sigma \sqrt{1-y^2}}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(-k \mu+\cos ^{-1}(y)-2 \pi \right) e^{-\frac{\left(k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)+2 \pi \right)^2}{2 k^2 \sigma^2}}}{k \sigma \sqrt{1-y^2}}}{4 \pi } $$

$$ -1< y < 1 $$

It looks like a cosine inverse distribution. Numerically also the distribution of $\cos(U_m k + \beta_m)$ looked like a cosine inverse one.

The $g(y)$ can be simplified to:

$$ g(y) = \frac{\text{erf}\left(\frac{k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)}{\sqrt{2} k \sigma}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{k \mu-\cos ^{-1}(y)+2 \pi }{\sqrt{2} k \sigma}\right)}{4 \pi  \sqrt{1-y^2}} $$

Comment: Ah! sorry for the confusion. In the code the iteration with m is actually the k in the equations. Let me correct this.

Comment: I have changed the code now.

Comment: The m in the equation is to show that the $U_m$ are drawn randomly from a distribution. The number of such points are `Nu` in the code. So, I create $U$ and $\beta$ as vectors of length `Nu`$.

Comment: thanks, removing comments

Comment: Please note that while the mean goes to zero, the _standard deviation_ goes like $\sqrt N$, so the probability to see fluctuation of order $\sqrt(100,000)\approx 300$ which is consistent with your results. To check convergence you should try running for 25,000, 50,000, 100,000 iterations and check the trend.

Comment: How is the $\sqrt{N}$ appears? I also saw that the standard deviation is less than $\sqrt{N}$ always and in the same order as $\sqrt{N}$ . I want to find this exactly as a function of $\sigma$, something like $\sigma_x = f(N, \sigma)$, where the $\sigma_x$ is the standard deviation of $x$ with the sequence of $k$.  I think it is affected by the $\sigma$, but how to know it exactly? I have done some more analysis and tried to find the distribution of $e^{i (U_m k + \beta_m) }$. I am updating the question with it. I don't know how to treat the sum after this and find statistics of $x$.

Comment: consider the variance: $|x|^2=xx^*$. This is $\sum_{mn}e^{ik(U_m-U_n)+i(\beta_m -\beta_n)}$, Taking the expectation, we are left with $m=n$ terms only. that is $\sum_{m,n}\delta_{m,n} = N$

Comment: @user619894 Is there a way I can find where (at which k) $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$ saturate ? Like for example, I set a precision of $\epsilon = 10^{-4}$ and I want to have an expression for the value of k where $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$ converge with this precision. Like $N_k = f(\epsilon, \mu, \sigma)$. This should be a function of the original $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the variable $U$ in the summation.

Comment: And one more thing I noticed. I plotted the $\sigma_x$ for both real and imaginary of $x$ at different $k$ samples to see convergence. It does converge but at a value $\sqrt{N/2}$ instead of $\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: I asked this new question on a new thread. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506012/convergence-of-a-function-having-a-big-summation-at-each-sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you are trying to find:

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{M\to \infty} \frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^{M}e^{i\left(kU_m + \beta_m\right)}
\end{align}

where $U_m \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $\beta_m \sim \mathcal U(-\pi, \pi)$. By the law of big number it is equivalent to compute the expectation of $e^{i(kU + \beta)}$. So let's do that:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[e^{i\left(kU+\beta\right)}\right] &= \mathbb E\left[e^{ikU}\right]\mathbb E\left[e^{i\beta}\right]\\
&= e^{ik\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2k^2}\frac{e^{i\pi} - e^{-i\pi}}{i(\pi - (-\pi))} = 0.
\end{align}

However if you had $e^{ik(U+\beta)} in that case the expectation would be:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[e^{ik\left(U+\beta\right)}\right] &= \mathbb E\left[e^{ikU}\right]\mathbb E\left[e^{ik\beta}\right]\\
&= e^{ik\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2k^2}\frac{e^{ik\pi} - e^{-ik\pi}}{ik(\pi - (-\pi))} = \frac1{k\pi}e^{ik\mu-\frac12\sigma^2k^2} \sin\left(k\pi\right).
\end{align}

Comment: I still have some doubts though. I am updating my question. Now, I will paste some code and results. Looking at the initial sum, I feel like it is true what the simulation is giving me. However, the expected value is always 0. How can I make a model with a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is still making me confused.