# Convergence of a function having a big summation at each sample

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, summation, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I have the following function.

$$ x(k) = \sum_{m} e^{i (U_m k + \beta_m)} $$

Here, $U_m$ samples are random numbers coming from a Gaussian distribution

$$U_m \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_u, \sigma_u)$$

and the $\beta_m$ values come randomly from a uniform distribution.

$$ \beta_m \sim \mathcal{U}[0, 2\pi] $$

If say I have $N$ samples of $U_m$ and $\beta_m$ for each $k$ in the series, I found that $x(k)$ will have a Gaussian distribution for a large number of $k$ samples (realizations) with a mean $\mu_x = 0$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma_x = \sqrt{N}$ (This comes from central limit theorem). Let's define the number of $k$ samples (realizations) as $M$.

Although through simulations I see that the value of $\sigma_x$ for both real and imaginary parts of $x(k)$ converge for a large $M$ with a value $\sigma_{x, converged} = \sqrt{N/2}$.

I wan to know if I can find an expression for $M$ as a function of $\mu_u, \sigma_u$ where convergence occurs for $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$. It can be based on a precision input $\epsilon$ like, $\epsilon = 10^{-4}$.

So, basically I want something like this:

$$ M|_{\mu_x, \sigma_x} = f(\epsilon, \mu_u, \sigma_u, N) $$

Comment: You should be more precise when you discuss "convergence" of an object that increases with $N$.

Comment: For a given $N$, as we know that the $\sigma_x$ will at the end converge to $\sqrt(N)$, I thought there should be a value of $N_k$ where it occurs. So, I defined the precision with $\epsilon$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: There are 2 limits that you are discussing: 1) large $N$, 2) many realizations of this large $N$, call this  $M$. If I understand you correctly, you mean that when you _fix_ $N$ and then do many measurements of $x(k)$, the std _converges_. However it is not clear to me that the value of $M$ needed for good convergence is independent of $N$.

Comment: Now, I understand. I am editing my question. $M$ will indeed depend on $N$. So, it is a function of $\epsilon, \mu_u, \sigma_u, N$ all 4 parameters.

Comment: Does it make sense now?